# How to pass forward slash(/) in path variable of uri?

Tags: java, rest, http, spring-boot

I have a rest api implementation as below -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getAllProductsByCategory/{category}/{pageNo}/{numberOfProducts}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ProductProperties> getAllProdutsByCategory(@PathVariable("category") String categoryID, @PathVariable("pageNo") int pageNo,
            @PathVariable("numberOfProducts") int numberOfProducts) {
        return productService.getProductsByCategory(categoryID, pageNo, numberOfProducts);
    }
```

Now i want to test this method where category variable should be like "men/clothing/jeans". I tried to use escape character %2F to replace forward slash, but had no luck. Is there any way to pass forward slash in uri ? I tried to google same question but didn't find any satisfactory answer.

Comment: Don't use path variable for value that can contain `/`. Use query parameter. Also, with RESTful, a URL refers to a resource, and the size of list to return is not a resource qualifier. It is a query parameter. Basically, your `getAllProductsByCategory` is a *query* endpoint, that needs query parameters. `/getAllProductsByCategory/men/clothing/jeans/3/20` is not a "resource", but `/getAllProductsByCategory?category=men/clothing/jeans&pageNo=3&numberOfProducts=20` is a good query.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion! It works. :-)